# How to use JSON to download audio file

Tags: javascript, php, json, api, download

I'm developing API to manage a system. So far I have manage to design things that I need to do with it's database, by sending data to the API and retrieving data from API.

What I need to do now is download audio files (.wav)  through my API.
Since i'm new to this JSON hope someone can give some help to me :)

Thank you!

Comment: You're getting it wrong. JSON is "javascript object notation" which can be used in request/response model for sending request params, storing response etc. It has nothing (directly) to do with downloading files.

Comment: JSON for an audio file? Nope not gonna happen. There is Binary JSON (BSON) you could look into.

Answer (score 3):

I would include the URL of the audio file in the JSON data, rather than try to embed the binary audio data somehow. Then your client can download the audio file through http or whichever protocol.

As simple as

```
{
'id':42,
'audio_url':'http://example.com/wav/audio_42.wav'
}
```